# Use of scipy.signal.lombscargle

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, astronomy

For class, we are trying to prove a simple example of the Lomb-Scargle Periodogram using the embedded package in scipy. There is little documentation on how to use this function, and I have not been able to find any help online. When I run the code, I get a value of ~6.3 for the main peak of the periodogram, as opposed to the expected ~23.3. The data that we are pulling from is a simple .dat file with lists of numbers. Here is the code, any ideas on what's happening?

```
import scipy as sp
import math as m
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lombscargle
import pylab as plt
from numpy import shape


x=[]
y=[]
nout = 10000
file=open("hv878_1945.dat", 'r')

for pair in file:
    xandy=pair.split()
    x.append(float(xandy[0]))
    y.append(float(xandy[2]))


x=np.asarray(x)
y=np.asarray(y)
f = np.linspace(0.1, 50, nout)

periodogram=sp.signal.spectral.lombscargle(x,y,f)
normval = x.shape[0]
plt.plot(f, np.sqrt(4*(periodogram/normval)))
plt.show()
```

Here is the file, if anybody wants to run it: http://www.mediafire.com/download/9a0aw9nc40r4c73/hv878_1945.dat

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What makes you say 23.3 is expected? Also, can you assert that the columns of interest are indeed the first and third column (python: 0 and 2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear you have the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518970/correct-way-to-use-scipy-signal-spectral-lombscargle). Basically you are not testing the frequency of interest and did not take into account that the frequencies passed to `lombscargle` are *angular* frequencies.

If you change your list of tested frequencies, you'll see there's a peak near the angular frequency of ~138, which corresponds to a frequency of 22.28 (=angular frequency /2/pi):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import lombscargle

plt.ion()
data = np.loadtxt('hv878_1945.dat')

ang_freq = np.linspace(.1, 25*6, 10000)
periodogram = lombscargle(data[:,0], data[:,2], ang_freq)
print(ang_freq[np.argmax(periodogram)]/2/np.pi)
plt.plot(ang_freq, periodogram)
```

[image: lombscargle periodogram]

I will make the same remark that Jaime made in the other SO question:

> you cannot rely on just looking for the `max` of periodogram to find the dominant frequency, because the harmonics may fool you.