# Aggregate Pandas dataframe and extract dominant frequencies

Tags: numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  Code                             A1    A2  A3 ...   B40
    Time
2000-01-01 00:00:10.730              NaN   1   NaN    NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:12.730              1     2   3      NaN
```

I want to aggregate data every one hour and calculate some stats. I used the following code for mean, std and skew:

```
grouped = Telemetry.groupby(Telemetry.index.floor('5T'))
# computing various stats
grouped = grouped.agg([ 'mean','std', 'skew'])
```

and my output is:

```
                                   A1                A2    ...   B40      
    Time                           mean std skew  mean std skew
2000-01-01 00:00:00.00             1    2    0    2    1    9
.
.
.
2010-01-01 00:01:00.00              1   2    3    1    0    1
```

I want to find the first two dominant frequencies for each window of time  but I am having a hard time to find a efficient way to do it for my data which is **non-uniformly** sampled. The out come that I am looking for is in this format:

```
                                   A1                            .....     
    Time                           mean std skew Freq1 Freq2    
2000-01-01 00:00:00.00             1    2    0    100   200      2    1    9
.
.
.
2010-01-01 00:01:00.00              1   2    3    400    500
```

I came across this question [Use of scipy.signal.lombscargle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973827/use-of-scipy-signal-lombscargle) but I am not sure how to implement this in my code and if this appropriate method to use.

I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Frequency analysis of non-uniformly-spaced data is such a niche feature that none of the `scipy.signal` functions (not even `lombscargle`) support it. There are various NUFFT libraries out there, but I can't really recommend any of them as simple and easy to use. The easiest thing would be to interpolate your data to uniform steps, if that's possible. Then you use any of the `fft`/`rfft` in Numpy/Scipy and define how you want to detect peaks, etc. Sorry this is probably not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Though, https://github.com/jakevdp/nufftpy will do what you want: nonuniform time domain to uniform frequency domain, includes a nice blog post to talk about it. Try this and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you @AhmedFasih I checked the library that you mentioned, it seems promising, I am going to try it out, I didn't find any other straightforward solution other than this so far.